# Are you allowed to work for your employer on a UK Visitor VISA

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to visit my friend in UK. I am an Indian citizen and working for a company in India. Due to Covid-19, I am working from home since Mar 2020.

When I visit UK, can I continue working for my employer while I am on UK Visitor Visa. The reason why I am asking is that my employer won't give me long leave (> 15 days) and I am planning to visit my friend for around 25-30 days.

Comment: The activities allowed by the Rules relating to a visitor visa are set out in https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities Remote working isn’t included

Comment: Thanks @Traveller. I would request my employer for 25-30 days leave.

Comment: In the USA, you need a work visa if you are physically present in the USA and work (for anyone anywhere in the world). I suspect other countries are the same. One small caribbean country offered work visas for people working online, so instead of sitting at home and typing on your computer you could do that in warmer climate near a beach, supporting their tourist industry.