# Can I WFH on a UK tourist visa and if so do I still need a NOC?

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, london, edinburgh

I am from India and want to go to UK for 2.5 weeks. I will first go to Paris for 4 days and then travel to London. I am planning to stay in Stevenage for about 10 days and explore London and surrounding places (travelling with a toddler so need time to explore). After that I will travel to Edinburgh for 3 days. Then I will return to Stevenage and stay with my friend for about 4 days and then take the flight back to India.

During my stay in UK, I will be partially be on leave, and partially continue WFH for my company in India. Is this allowed and will a NOC from employer still be required?

Comment: You can't work on a tourist visa. Some countries have special WFH permits, but I'm not aware of any for the UK.

Comment: @Mast it is working for a UK company that is not allowed. [Here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor) it says you may attend business meetings, but not work *for a UK company* or as self-employed. [This page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-on-business) lists the permitted business activities on a standard visitor visa.

Comment: In [this previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162673/are-you-allowed-to-work-for-your-employer-on-a-uk-visitor-visa) a commenter says "not work for anyone anywhere in the world" but that is not what UK gov webpage says. There must be some middle ground: you might get a business phone call while on vacation, surely that can't be prohibited?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I get a UK visitor visa anyway?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/should-i-get-a-uk-visitor-visa-anyway)

Comment: An extract from the [duplicate's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/151939/62763) of the "Home Office's Visit Guidance for immigration officers": says *be satisfied that the visitor is not coming to work or make the UK their main place of work*. The purpose of the visit is tourism.

Comment: @WeatherVane on this site and the rest of the internet you can find actual stories of people who were refused leave to enter after disclosing to UK immigration officers their intention to work remotely for a foreign employer while visiting the UK.  Keeping up with e-mail and phone calls is one thing; planning to spend an entire day or more working "on the clock" is another matter entirely.

Comment: If in doubt, IOs can (and do) examine baggage, phone, laptop, etc, to see if there is evidence of intent to work.  Refusal to submit to a search may result in the person being refused leave to enter, or could constitute an offence under section 26(1)(b) of the Immigration Act 1971, and / or could lead to a device being seized under paragraph 15A(7) of Schedule 2 to that Act."

Answer (score 9):

Remote working while visiting the UK is explicitly covered in the latest guidance, published Oct 2021.

*“Visitors are permitted to undertake activities relating to their employment overseas remotely whilst they are in the UK, such as responding to emails or answering phone calls. However, you should check that the applicant’s main purpose of coming to the UK is to undertake a permitted activity, rather than specifically to work remotely from the UK. Where the applicant indicates that they intend to spend a large proportion of their time in the UK and will be doing some remote working, you should ensure that they are genuinely employed overseas and are not seeking to work in the UK.”*

AFAIK (based on the numerous references to it in questions on TSE) it is standard practice for Indian applicants to submit a NOC from their employer when applying for a UK visa. Doing so should help satisfy the final point quoted in the extract from the guidance above. So *yes*, a NOC is still required.

Source: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf